# Android using rabbitmq singleton connection

Tags: android, connection, singleton, rabbitmq

I need a design patter to make a rabbitmq singleton connection that I can that will restart on connection loss/ internet provider switch.
My problem is that the connection is realised on another thread (asynctask) due to android main thread policy.
I use this connection for two services that consume and push.

```
    public class RabbitSingletonConnection {

        public static RabbitSingletonConnection instance;
        private Connection connection;

        private RabbitSingletonConnection() {

        }

        public static RabbitSingletonConnection getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new RabbitSingletonConnection();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void Connect(RabbitMQConnectionCallback callback) {
            if (connection != null && connection.isOpen()) {
                LogUtil.hecsLog("RabbitSingletonConnection", "already connected");
                callback.onConnect(connection);
                return;
            }
            new RabbitConnectAsync(callback).execute("ip","user", "pass");
        }

        public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        public Connection getConnection() {
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

Problem is that this `LogUtil.hecsLog("RabbitSingletonConnection", "already connected");` never occurs.
I have been digging and discovered something "Thread safe singleton using classloader declaration or ENUM approach", but this does not include a callback method.

EDIT

```
RabbitSingletonConnection.getInstance().Connect(new RabbitMQConnectionCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnect(Connection result) {
            if (result != null && result.isOpen()){
              RabbitSingletonConnection.getInstance().setConnection(result);
              LogUtil.hecsLog(LOG, "Service has started");
            }


        }
    });
```

This is a example [Is it necessary to rebuild RabbitMQ connection each time a message is to be sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910502/is-it-necessary-to-rebuild-rabbitmq-connection-each-time-a-message-is-to-be-sent) but I cannot make the connection in the constructor because it needs a thread to handle `TimeoutException`.

My goal is to start service after the rabbitMQ async task connects.

Do I need dependency injection?

Comment: Does RabbitConnectAsync method call setConnection? Because if it doesn't then the connection variable will always be null.

Comment: Yes, both services do. The problem is that all my app is thread based.

Comment: The second service get triggered while the first is still connecting, so it returns a null connection.

Comment: Glad thats sorted out :)

Comment: Sorry, but I have never used RabbitMQ, so I cannot help you.

Comment: The ideea is keeping a sigle connection active in a singleton, the down side is that it cannot connect on main thread (network operation)
One of my services is sticky so I need it to start the connection if app is closed.
@CommonsWare do you have any design in mind so I my connection can never be null? I'm talking about connectivity loss and connectivity gane / app being killed and restarted.

Comment: "do you have any design in mind so I my connection can never be null?" -- by definition, that is impossible, as the user can terminate your process at any point, let alone Android. When your process starts back up, you would need to reconnect to your server. beyond that, I do not understand much about your problem space, sorry.

Comment: "never be null" ok, that was exaggerated.The logic is simple, I use a live RabbitMQ connection, I want my app to be able to reconnect to the server when needed, just like facebook or other messaging apps.
Single difference is that they use XMPP connection instead of RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, I was starting/stopping the services on connectivity gain/loss. I looked at the facebook app and the services never stop, so the logic answer is to reset the workflow in the service not the service itslef.